# Laptop Shut down during installation of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot-failure

I started installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my Gateway laptop, to replace windows 7 that already was on it. Sometime during the installation the computer shut down due to my niece pressing the power button, because she thought I left it on and forgot. I'm guessing it got as far as deleting windows before the shutdown.
Now it boots up, shows the Gateway startup screen then goes blank except for the cursor in the upper left corner. I can't seem to get the cd to load, I hear it run but nothing else, and I can't figure out how to have it boot from the cd as I just got this thing.

Obliviously I messed up the program files badly, how do I fix it correctly? Is there another version of ubuntu I can install that will fix this and turn this back into a working laptop instead of a brick?

I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you were going to delete Windows anyway than nothing bad has happened. You just need to go into BIOS setup (by pressing F2 or Del while on the "Gateway startup screen") and make sure your CD drive or USB stick comes first in the list of boot devices. Then you reboot and the machine should start booting from the Ubuntu media.

Comment: Actually I just fixed it, wound up downloading the 32bit version and managed to figure out what should boot up first. I guess I should have just kept at it a little longer.